# Recommendations for C++ profiling tools

Tags: c++, code-analysis

Can anyone recommend any tools for compile and runtime analysis of C++ code? I'm being hit day after day with requests to identify where certain overloads of functions are being used in a very large code base.

My current method involves a combination of (a) text search using grep / find and (b) spoofing the include files to comment out the overloads in question, and fully recompiling thus breaking the build where the overloads are used. As you can imagine this is very time consuming.

I'm doing this on a Red Hat Linux platform, by the way.

Comment: You want to statically know where the call sites are for specific methods?   Is there something special about the fact that they are overloaded, or just that it is hard to figure out which of the N overloads is called from a particular site?

Comment: I don't think this is 'off topic'. True, I asked for a tool recommendation but the closure comment states *"... Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* If you read the question, I do both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used a combination of gprof and a script called [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) which gives you a call graph showing how much time is spent in each method.

See this article on [gprof](http://cplusplusworld.com/gnugprof.html).  Also take a look at:

[Optimizing C/C++ programs using the GProf profiler](http://www.unix-tutorials.com/go.php?id=321)

Here is an example call graph showing time spent in each method ( taken from the gprof2dot page):

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this. One question: from your response and the gprof note you referenced it looks like gprof is good at runtime analysis, but what about compile time? I really want to know not what paths the code *actually* traverse but potentially what it *could*. I'm not so bothered about performance timings at this stage but want to be able to answer comprehensively questions like "list all the places in the code base where `X( const char * )` gets called"

Comment: @Robin Welch:  Sounds like you want something like cscope http://cscope.sourceforge.net/.  Another tool which you might find useful is ctags http://ctags.sourceforge.net/.  Those are two of the main tools used for navigating the Linux kernel source code.

Answer (score 3):

I used Intels VTune in the past and found it very helpful.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune/

Answer (score 3):

take a look at `valgrind`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html). Now it is part of the valgrind project.

It has very nice GUI to review the results : [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)

Both are available for your distro.

Answer (score 1):

I second @RA's recommendation of Intel VTune as worthy of looking at.  Don't turn your nose up at `gprof`, it's ubiquitous and is a good start.  You may be able to get the information you want from your debugger -- which is ?

If you told us what compiler you are using, we might be able to tell you what features it has for helping you.

Comment: It's gcc version 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-34) Please don't mock - it's not my choice but the clients.

Comment: @Robin Welch: no intention to mock, but can't help much either with GCC.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [TAU](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/home.php), which although it can be a pain to configure, it is quite powerful.